# How to enable other controls when a user is typing in a text box and disable if he deletes or text box is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, disabled-control

I'm trying to disable a group of controls based on a text box. if the user has entered a value in that text box the controls should be enabled and if the user deletes value or if it remains empty the controls should be disabled.

Comment: One workflow might be: 
1. Make other controls initialy disabled.
2. Listen for change event on the text box
3. Check for a valid state of the check box in the event handler and enable/disable the rest of the controls

Comment: _“I'm trying to [...]”_ - then why aren’t we seeing anything of your “trying”? Please go read [ask], and [mcve].

Comment: CBroe..Sorry, i missed inserting code here. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume your text box ID is **TxtBoxName**
and assume you put your controls inside div or any other container and its name is **controls** , the following is my solution

```
$('#TxtBoxName').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 0)
    {
        $('#controls').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#controls').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

Comment: you are welcome, you can also use another event like blur,click , etc .....

Answer (score 0):

What kind of control do you want to disable? If you want to disable form controls, you can use below code:

```js
$( '#txtName' ).on( 'input change paste', function() {
  var diasabled = !$.trim( $( this ).val() );

  $( 'input' ).not( this ).each( function() {
    $( this ).prop( 'disabled', diasabled )
  } )
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frm" action="#" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="txtName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="txtFamily">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtTel" disabled>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="txtEmail">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="txtEmail" disabled>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Comment: change, paste and input!! great, thanks for the help. Have a nice day.

Comment: you are welcome. most of mobile web browsers only support `input` event. So other events like `keypress`, `keydown`, `keyup` and .. not working on them.